# adding a new column after performig subtraction and division between two columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data set :

dataset A,

```
 ID bidding_price   Sale_price

 10 74.88             67.27
 11 23.1              18.14
 12 62.5              56.14
 13 34.5              27.09
 14 55.32             49.69
 15 900               706.77
 16 260.84            260.84
```

I would like to add a column diff by performing the following operation

```
diff =(Bidding_price-Sale_price)/(Sale_price*100%)
```

and the output should look like this:

```
ID  bidding_price   Sale_price     diff
10  74.88             67.27      0.113126208
11  23.1              18.14      0.273428886
12  62.5              56.14      0.113288208
13  34.5              27.09      0.273532669
14  55.32             49.69      0.113302475
15  900               706.77     0.273398701
16  260.84            260.84     0.00
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: This is very basic. After reading an introduction or tutorial to R you should be able to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use the awesome `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame("id"=c(1, 2, 3),
                 "bidding_price"=c(10,11,12),
                 "sale_price"=c(9,10,11))

df <- mutate(df, diff=(bidding_price - sale_price)/sale_price)
```

The output is

```
  id bidding_price sale_price       diff
1  1            10          9 0.11111111
2  2            11         10 0.10000000
3  3            12         11 0.09090909
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to use `dplyr` here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is A, then something like this

```
A$diff =(A$Bidding_price-A$Sale_price)/(A$Sale_price*100%)
```

would work for you?